# Vlcj - How to get the timestamp using Java?

Tags: java, timestamp, vlcj

sorry for bothering you but I have another question about **vlcj**. For this school project, I need to know how to catch the timestamp of the video that I'm currently playing on my MediaPlayer and add this information to a database.

At the moment I'm using the **getTime()** method:

```
start = (int)mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().getTime();
```

The "start" is the column's name (integer type) of my database where this information is stored. It's ok achieve the current play-back time like this but if I can catch the timestamp like a camcorder (where you know when the video was recorded) that would be a big help for what my program is going to be used in the future.

I searched online and the **API** of the vlcj but I can't find informations. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance for any possible answer and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for what I know, there isn't a "direct" solution for this but my teacher suggest me to make a five steps path instead of one. And thanks to her now is possible to get the time of the video when it was recorded. So here are the instructions:

```
//I'll take the time where I'm in the video
long time = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().getTime();

//I'll take the lenght of the video
long lenght = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().getLength();

//Now I need to know the path
File file = choosed.getSelectedFile();
String uri = file.getPath();
Path path = Paths.get(uri);

//I'll take the last time this video was modified and
//transform that information in milliseconds
FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
long lastModifiedTime = fileTime.toMillis();

//I'll make a simple equation
start = (lastModifiedTime - lenght) + time;
```

I change the start integer type in a long type for having a more readable code and don't having: "start = (int)(lastModifiedTime - lenght) + (int)time".

I hope that could help someone else. Sorry for my English and have a nice day!

P.S. Forgot to add a
[link](https://www.epochconverter.com) where you can convert the millisecond time in 
year, month, day, hour...

Comment: Well, you are using the last modified time of the file on the filesystem. There is no guarantee this has any relationship to the time the video itself was actually created.